# Nativescrit Vue - Can I access my Vue instance in my main.js?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

I am developping an app in nativescript + vue and I have an issue selecting the target page when the user resumes the app.
In my main.js I have:

```vue
new Vue({
  render: h => h('frame', [h(HomePage)])
}).$start()
```

And what I would like to do is something like this:

```vue
application.on("resume", () => {
     this.$navigateTo(SomeOtherPage)
})
```

However, `this` is undefined here and I cannot navigate to my desired page when the app is resumed.

I tried giving a name to my Vue like `const my_vue = new Vue({...})` and then call `my_vue.$navigateTo(...)` but `my_vue` is undefined as well.

Is there any way to make this work or is this the wrong approach to achieve what I'm trying to do ?

Comment: arrow function doesn't have `this` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: My point is, in any of my .vue files, I would call this.$navigateTo but since I have no this in my main.js, I don't know how to call $naviageteTo on resume

Comment: @FabriceDucloux How exactly did you do it so `my_vue` was undefined? This a reasonable way to do what you're trying to do this and `my_vue` shouldn't be undefined because `new Vue` returns an instance. I assume there was circular dependency, this is a common way in JS to get undefined where it certainly shouldn't be. Please, provide a piece of code that can replicate the problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @EstusFlask Well, I made it work whilst trying to provide you a piece of code to replicate the problem. My mistake was I defined my variable without removing the `.$start()`. What I did was `const my_vue = new Vue({...}).$start()` so my_vue was undefined, instead of doing `const my_vue = new Vue({...})` and then `my_vue.$start()`. Sorry for not realising it sooner and thank you for the help

Comment: Glad you sorted this out. My personal recommendation is to use Typescript, it efficiently allows to avoid this kind of bugs.